# ObservableCollection needs three more methods/properties. Does some other collection have them?

Tags: mvvm, silverlight-4.0, mvvm-light

I have looked around a bit for this--can't find the proper collection

Here is the signature of my desired ViewModel. There are some interesting 
alternatives out there David Hill's CollectionViewModel or ObservableDictionary(Of TKey, TValue) on codeplex. But for now, I would like a built-in collection (for SL4) that handles this. Thanks

```
public class myViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyDataType> MyCollection;
    private ObservableCollection<MyDataType> _myCollection;

    public CurrentItem<MyDataType>() { return _myCollection.CurrentItem;} 

    public int GetCurrentIndex()  { return _myCollection.CurrentIndex;}
    public SetCurrentIndex(int Index)   { _myCollection.CurrentIndex = Index;}
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built-in collection that provides this.  However, you could just store the `currentIndex` value as a private `int` inside your ViewModel, and refer to it for the current index methods, as well as use it for `CurrentItem<T>()`.

Comment: Well, like I say, programming is an exploration into my stupidity. I was looking for a method with a name like 'Item' or something. Now, in response to your answer I looked again and see that ObservableCollection has an indexer! var anItem = myCollection[7];    Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

But do we really need something like this? You can always bind to "ViewModel.MyCollection/" to get the currently selected item